# Sharing memory-only NeDB instance in multiple Electron BrowserWindows

Tags: node.js, electron, nedb

We are developing an app using Electron and Vue.js. In our app we are using NeDB for temporarily storing JSON documents after having received (and decrypted) them from a Firebase Database. A requirement of the app is, that the decrypted data stays in memory and is not saved to disk during the user session. Therefore we use NeDB with the `inMemoryOnly` flag.

Our goal is to show reports for contents of the database in a different BrowserWindow to print / save them as PDF.

We tried to initialize the database using a global variable, but unfortunately the database content was empty. Is there another possibility to access the database from within a different BrowserWindow?

Comment: why don't you use ipc, when the new browserwindow ( where you want to show the db content ) is created , send an ipc message to the window were the information was saved, once that window receives the message, send the initialise database back to the browserwindow where you want the content to show . if you can show us a little bit of the code it will help

Comment: What if we want to do more queries and even some complex queries to the database? Then we have to send queries via IPC, do computation in the original BrowserWindow and then send the results back to the new BrowserWindow? This seems to represent too much of an implementation/communication overhead for me?